# Function-pointer to comparison operator

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm currently trying to grasp both function overloading and function pointers.
In order to shorten a piece of code I want/need to make a function pointer to a comparison operator. In my original code i loop trough and compare lots of pairs of float variables.
My actions after the comparison is dependent on wether a third semi-static variable is positive or negative. In this version i either have to check the value of the semi-static variable for every pair or I have to replicate a lot of code.

```
double angleRight; //This variable is either positive or negative and is not reassigned for the purpose of this code

while (points.size() > 2){
siz = points.size();
for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++){
  if (angleRight > 0 && points[i].angle < 0){
<Do something>
    <remove points[i]>
  } else if (angleRight < 0 && points[i].angle > 0){
  <Do something else>
      <remove points[i]>
  }
}
```

If I instead could evaluate angleRight once and then store a function-pointer to either operator> or operator<, I would be able to use this function-pointer instead and could avoid evaluating angleRight as well as the entire 'else'-block.
I have tried to understand function pointers and (I think) I see how I could have managed if i wanted access to an overloaded member-function.

```
//This compiles
class Bs{
  public:
  float x;
  bool operator< (Bs y){
    return x < y.x;
  }
};
bool (Bs::*compare) (Bs) /*const*/ = &Bs::operator<;
```

But what i really want to do/imagine is something like this:

```
//This does not compile:
bool (*compar) (float) /*const*/ = &float::operator<;
```

**EDIT:**
Making the two functions 'greater' and 'less' does what I want:

```
bool greater(float x, float y){
  return x > y;
}
bool less(float x, float y){
  return x < y;
}

bool (*compar) (float, float) = (angleRight < 0)? &greater : &less;
```

But it annoys me that I actually have to write the functions. Is there no way of directly accessing the float-operator> ?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of this question? Is it because you are "trying to grasp both function overloading and function pointers", or do you actually want to make the routine more efficient?

Comment: Both. I am writing code to learn better (prettier or more effective) c++ code. I am trying to improve my code but obtaining "a deeper undersatanding" of the language is equally important. Using a pointer to a function would have seemed both pretty and effective to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ way of doing things like this is not by accepting a function pointer, but by accepting a *function-like object*.

An example:

```
template <class T, class Cmp> int cmp(T x, T y, Cmp cmp_func = std::less) {
    return cmp_func(x, y) - cmp_func(y, x);
}
```

In this example we don't care exactly what `Cmp` is, as long as it supports `operator()` with two operands.

If your function accepts a function-like-object you can use standard objects like `std::less` automatically too solving this question.

Comment: Making the two functions 'greater' and 'less' does what I want, but it annoys me that I actually have to write the functions. Is there no way of directly accessing the float-operator> ?